# Layout problems on Wagtail

Tags: wagtail, shared-hosting

I installing Wagtail on shared hosting. Instead of normal main and admin page there is view like that [image]

Comment: I put an answer below but without more information about what kind of shared hosting, whether the issue is happening on the hosting only (ie. not local development) and your setings.py configs it will be hard to give any more specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your static assets are not correctly built (CSS/JS).

If you are running locally you may need to run the [Django management command collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic).

```sh
./manage.py collectstatic
```

If you are encountering this on the server, here are some relevant questions that may help.

- [django collectstatic on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761868/django-collectstatic-on-server)
- [Django: CSS Is not not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446325/django-css-is-not-not-working)